How do I create the switching signals for my DAB converter?
I am currently designing a DAB converter (work in progress) and I'd like to know if there is an easier method for driving the switching signals than the method I have below using a TC4425AVPA to generate the signal. I am also asking how I would add a delay onto the C and D signals.

This driver does not need to be a PWM signal (which is what the chip I use produces) as it will have a constant 0.5 duty cycle with a continuous input. This schematic was taken from a previous boost converter design and has been adapted for the DAB.

Dual Active Bridge and not Digital Audio Broadcast?

It looks like the gate drive is copied over from some hard-switching full-bridge. By delay on C and D, would you like phase shift control?

@winny yes, not sure how i would add that control to the second half of the converter

A second gate driver. If you need to set the deadband between A&B and C&D too, you need four independent channels.
